# How do I create a PDF page from jpg image taken with IPAD camera?

Tags: ios, pdf

I can create the PDF and add the jpg image to it. The problem is I am only getting a very small part of the image at a very low resolution. How can I put the picture taken with the iPad camera into a PDF? Any help will be appreciated.

```
#import "MTViewController.h"
#define kPadding 20

@interface MTViewController ()
{
    CGSize _pageSize;
}
@end

@implementation MTViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

 - (IBAction)didClickOpenPDF
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"NextPDF.pdf"];

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:pdfPath])
    {
        ReaderDocument *document = [ReaderDocument withDocumentFilePath:pdfPath password:nil];

        if (document != nil)
        {
            ReaderViewController *readerViewController = [[ReaderViewController alloc]                                  initWithReaderDocument:document];
            readerViewController.delegate = self;
            readerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
            readerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
            [self presentModalViewController:readerViewController animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (IBAction)didClickMakePDF
{
    [self setupPDFDocumentNamed:@"NextPDF" Width:1024 Height:768];
    [self beginPDFPage];
    UIImage *anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Test_1.JPG"];
    CGRect imageRect = [self addImage:anImage
                  atPoint:CGPointMake((_pageSize.width/2)-(anImage.size.width/2), + kPadding)];
    [self beginPDFPage];
    [self finishPDF];
}
- (void)setupPDFDocumentNamed:(NSString*)name Width:(float)width Height:(float)height
{
    _pageSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    NSString *newPDFName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf", name];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:newPDFName];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfPath, CGRectZero, nil);
}

- (void)beginPDFPage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, _pageSize.width, _pageSize.height), nil);
}

- (void)finishPDF
{
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}

- (CGRect)addImage:(UIImage*)image atPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [image drawInRect:imageFrame];
    return imageFrame;
}

- (void)dismissReaderViewController:(ReaderViewController *)viewController
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame you create in your `addImage:atPoint:` method is all wrong. You need to create an frame that actually fits within the page.

Your page is 1024x768 (which is a strange size for a PDF). A PDF should be sized in points with a density of 72 pip (points per inch).

You then specify that the image's origin should be the center of the page. Then you set the image's frame to be the size of the image. The full image is going to be much bigger than the PDF page size.

If you want the image to fill the page, set the image's frame to be `0, 0, 1024, 768` (adjust as needed for any margin you might want). Then draw the full sized image into that frame. The image will be scaled to fit. You may also need to adjust the frame to have the same aspect ration as the original image to avoid the image from being distorted.